How to pass information back to upstream modules in http process pipeline?
I am working on a go server application based on go-chi v5, a http process pipeline is built up with middlewares and some handler functions, and http request flows in this pipeline, from middlewares to handler.
The problem is in middleware some information is unknown, those information can only be known later. For example, I have an instrumentation middleware measures the request handling time (egress - ingress) and logs the error when request handling hit any errors, obviously those kind of information is only available when request reaches the finally handler implements business logic, there is no way to know how long will request processing take or whether request will encounter any errors when request is passing through instrumentation middleware.
However, in golang the only way to pass information when process http request is using the context object, the information flows from upstream to downstream, I can add information like requestID using context.WithValue, so downstream modules can use the key to extract the requestID from context object, but there is no way to pass information from downstream to upstream.
Seems I need a mechanism to setup a callback hook in http process pipeline, which can be invoked when request pops up from the stack/pipeline, but I cannot find such a mechanism, does anyone have a good suggestion on this? Thanks.

You might want to look into OpenTelemetry for issues like that. Usually
you try to collect events for a request ID and correlate them later. It's sufficient to know when a request started and when it has ended, there is no need to immediately calculate some duration in the middleware. Keeping state for every request served is not very economical.
